# ABSPATH in Windows

Tags: constants

I'm having a a pain in the head using the `ABSPATH` constant in Windows.
Addressing files and folders in Windows is usually done using the `\` (forward-slash) character while for Linux the character would be `/` (backslash).
Unfortunately the `ABSPATH` in Wordpress is defined with only Linux in mind (putting a `/` at the end of it).
I wonder if I can over-ride it's definition since in `wp-config.php` it's defined under an `if` clause which indicates it can be defined elsewhere.

**Problem detalis:**

1. I'm running on `localhost`
2. The problem is with the `statpress-visitors` internal addressing.

This is how it addresses the files:

```
ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/' . dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)) . '/def/os.dat'
```

And this is what I get as output:

```
C:\wamp\www\wp/wp-content/plugins/statpress-visitors/def/os.dat
```

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on _2_ ? Can it be narrowed down to specific place / function in plugin that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does support both styles of slashes in path.

I am not sure if `ABSPATH` definition is safe to edit:

- *pro* it's in `wp-config.php`
- *con* it's says to not edit following above it

Myself I just use it as is, or replace slashes to make them uniform when putting path together. If that doesn't work for you please provide specific examples where this causes issues.